# knowing vs know

Tags: grammaticality

May I know which are grammatical in the following

> 1. It is often more important to know what you cannot do **than knowing**
>    what you can do
> 2. It is often more important to know what you cannot do **than know** what you can do

Above using know, my reasoning is previously I have used **to know** what...**than know**，but it seems not correct, but I am not sure why.

> 3. It is often more important to know what you cannot do
>    **than** what you can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't special rules of grammar preventing you from writing clumsy sentences that arbitrarily switch between verb forms. It's purely a matter of *style*.

As implied there, it's *bad style* in example #1 to have a "contrast-based" sentence construction with an infinitive *(to know)* on one side, and a gerund *(knowing)* on the other. They don't "balance".

OP's example #2 is okay because it has infinitives on both sides (with the implicit ***to*** component [elided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) the second time). Some people might be critical of that elision, precisely *because* it detracts from the "mirrored halves" construction. I'd take that line myself in the *written* format, but in speech I think it helps the prosody/flow - the speaker's in a hurry, because there's still a bunch more words before he gets to the all-important contrast of ***can*** with previously-specified ***cannot***.

---

OP's example #3 just goes further with the elision (#4 could just delete the final ***do***). Again, it's a stylistic choice of no real significance. *Idiomatically* I'm sure most people would use ***can't*** rather than ***cannot*** (it's not "informal" here), but context and personal preference come in many varieties.